# Servlet filter chain order is changing on continous refresh

Tags: java, servlets, filter, servlet-filters

In my application we have implemented several filters. For example I have three filters

1. Locale Filter
2. License Filter
3. Login Filter

The order is working fine in normal case. But when I am giving continuous refresh it sometimes skips the License Filter (execution then is: Locale Filter ->  Login Filter).

Is there any way to avoid this? The order should not change even when I continuously refresh. The order should be followed every time.

```
public class LicenseFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {

}


@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        try {
                    LOGGER.info("In LicenseFilter");    
                    licenseValidator.validate();
                    chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }catch (Exception excep) {  
                     LOGGER.error("License Error " + excep.getMessage());               
                     req.setAttribute("error", excep.getMessage());
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req
                            .getRequestDispatcher("license_list.action");
                    dispatcher.forward(req, res);
            } 
        } 

}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException {

    WebApplicationContext wctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(cfg
            .getServletContext());
    licenseValidator = (licenseValidator) wctx.getBean("licenseValidator");
    ctx = cfg.getServletContext().getContextPath();

}
```

}

web.xml

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<display-name>web</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>META-INF/beans-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

   <filter>
    <filter-name>localeFilter </filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.LocaleFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>localeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>licenseFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.licenseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>licenseFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
 <filter>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.filter.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: How do you know, that the License filter is skipped? Can you attach a snippet of your license filter's doFilter method?

Comment: Using Logger I came to know that License filter is skipped . If I dont have any valid license I should redirect license page else next filter should execute. Everything works well.  When I give continuous request (refresh) license filter is bypassed and next filter is executing

Comment: What about the web.xml? Is the filter's url-pattern defined correctly?

Comment: Yes every thing defined correctly thats why its working in normal case with no issues. So please understand it not works only on continues refresh .